# ToFixed in Javascript.. is it a bug

Tags: javascript

In my case

```
var num = "5.5499";
var numResult = parseFloat(num).toFixed(1);
```

Now here numResult is returing 5.5 and not 5.6

Is this ToFixed function at all reliable... Can anybody suggest a good alternative.

Comment: There is nothing inaccurate... `5.5499` rounded is not `5.6`.

Comment: I think the OP is expecting `5.5499` to round to `5.55` first, then to `5.6`. But that isn't how rounding works, only the `n + 1` digit is considered, i.e. `5.5499 -> 5.54 -> 5.5`.

Comment: You can fix it twice- var n=5.5499;(+n.toFixed(2)).toFixed(1)==>5.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rounding `5.5499` to the second decimal place gives us `5.5`, as `5.5` is closer to `5.5499` than `5.6`

For more details see [the Wikipedia page on rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding)

If you wanted to round up, then some monkeying around with `Math` is required:

```
var numResult = Math.ceil(parseFloat(num) * 10) / 10;
```

Comment: Thanks buddy... sounds like a more mature answer